# "created at" or "created in"

Tags: grammar

I'm not sure which one I should use:

> Created in ____

or

> Created at ____

Answer (score 98, accepted):

*On* for days and dates, *in* for duration, *at* for precise times, including full dates that include the time:

> Created in 3 hours and 15 minutes.
>
> Created on the 13th of July
>
> Created on 2013-07-13
>
> Created at 14:35
>
> Created at 2013-07-13 14:35
>
> Created at 2013-07-13T14:35:00Z (when ISO dates are appropriate).

Comment: Thanks for this explanation - I've been wondering about this

Comment: Thanks. What about *nothing*? I mean something like **"Created 2013-07-13"**.